# HOW TO DELETE OR OVERRIDE _NAV CSS FILE FORM BOOTSTRAP CDN

Tags: magento2, css, scss

_nav file in bootstrap CDN damaging my navbar style So 
HOW TO DELETE OR OVERRIDE _NAV.sccs FILE FORM BOOTSTRAP CDN?

I have added bootstrap CDN to Magento 2 it changed my main menu alignment how to fix it??

display: block fixing it instead of display: flex CSS style but I don't know how to add it

how to add display:block css style to override display: flex bootstrap CDN css style in _nav.scss file
I have already added 
.nav {
display: block;
}
but it doesnt work

Comment: _navigation.less file ??????

Comment: I have added bootstrap cdn to magento 2 it changed my main menu alignment how to fix it??

Comment: display: block fixing it instead of display: flex css style but I don't know how to add it

Answer (score 0):

If you have added .nav {display: block;} to your custom CSS, try adding !important like this:

.nav {
display: block !important;
}

Sorry I can't add this as a comment (I need 50 reputation).